# How to remove parenthesis from elements inside a list in python

Tags: python

How do I remove the square parenthesis from each element from the list
For example if I have
list = [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d']
how can I get an output
['a','b','c','d']

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `for` loop. Code:

```py
l = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d']]
new_l = []

for elem in l:
    new_l.append(elem[0])
```

Comment: FWIW, `new_l = [e[0] for e in l]` would suffice too…